# Parsing attributes using Groovy's XmlParser

Tags: xml, groovy

I have a short xml I want to get some attribs out of it, but I get some error

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.NodeList.attribute() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [dbHost]
```

My code

```
def temp="""
 <nodemetadata>
    <imx:IMX xmlns:imx="http://com.abc.imx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:domainservice="http://com.abc.isp.metadata.domainservice/2">
    <domainservice:GatewayNodeConfig imx:id="U:pgwraGgJbC99YpLSQ" consolePort="13993" consoleShutdownPort="4613" domainName="D_1163931" nodeName="N_1163931" dbConnectivity="ID_1">
    <address imx:id="ID_2" xsi:type="common:NodeAddress" host="beetle" httpPort="1391" port="1392"/>
    <portals>
    <NodeRef imx:id="ID_3" xsi:type="common:NodeRef" address="ID_2" nodeName="N_1163931"/>
    </portals>
    </domainservice:GatewayNodeConfig>
    <domainservice:DBConnectivity imx:id="ID_1" dbEncryptedPassword="AfaFnEtrQkOKFTVBYIIQ%3D%3D" dbHost="forer" dbName="ORCL" dbPort="1521" dbType="ORACLE" dbUsername="mka"/>
    </imx:IMX>
</nodemetadata>
"""

def records = new XmlParser().parseText(temp)
def dbHost='dbHost'
println "Host = "+records.'imx:IMX'.'domainservice:DBConnectivity'.attribute("dbHost")
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use:

```
def attrname = 'dbHost'
println "Host = "+records.'imx:IMX'.'domainservice:DBConnectivity'.@"$attrname"
```

The problem is that you have a `NodeList`, not a `Node`, so to get the `attribute` method to work, you need to either do:

```
// Call attribute on the first Node element
println "Host = "+records.'imx:IMX'.'domainservice:DBConnectivity'[0].attribute( attrname )
```

Or

```
// Call attribute on each Node in the NodeList, and return a list of attributes
println "Host = "+records.'imx:IMX'.'domainservice:DBConnectivity'*.attribute( attrname )
```

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Updated my answer with a better explanation of what's going wrong in your example

Comment: Ya even i remembered after your initial solution so i tried `println "Host = "+records.'imx:IMX'.'domainservice:DBConnectivity'[0].@dbHost` and it worked. Thanks again! :)